# Passing variables between a PHP module and a PHP script

Tags: php, custom-module, variable

I am trying to pass some **variable** from a PHP module (**Sourcerer**) to *custom PHP script* using Sessions method ([as posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16778482/3565182)). The method works fine between two PHP scripts but when I tried to implement it between a module and a script, it fails.

### Overview of the my method :

> Code inside **php module** :

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Welcome to page #1';
$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
?>
```

> Code inside **php script** :

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Welcome to page #2<br />';
echo $_SESSION['favcolor'];
?>
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use using `$_SESSION` with Joomla, but instead `JFactory::getSession()`.

Try the following:

**Module:**

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('favcolor', 'green');
```

**PHP file:**

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->get('favcolor');
```

Comment: As always. It's you, my hero :)

Comment: any idea about this : http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17706/joomla-sessions-within-a-loop-passing-only-a-single-value