# Joomla sessions within a loop passing only a single value

Tags: php, jsession

I need to pass some variables from `one PHP module` to `another PHP module` within a loop and at the same time display the module multiple times as well. I use `Joomla sessions` for passing variables and its giving me some trouble. Only the **last value** of the variable gets passed to the second module, meaning only the value attained by a variable when the `loop is over` is passed to the second module even though I use `sessions within the loop.`

> **First Module**

```
for ($i=1;$i<5;$i++) 
{
    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $session->set('number', $i);

    // calling second module by position

    $modules = JModuleHelper::getModules("second-position");
    foreach($modules as $mod)
      {
         echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($mod, $attribs);
      }
}
```

> **Second Module**

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$x = $session->get('number');

echo $x;
```

> **Output, I get**

`4`
`4`
`4`
`4`

> **Desired Output**

`1`
`2`
`3`
`4`

What's wrong, and how to correct it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont put JFactory::getSession inside the loop. Put it outside. Not the actual answer but will improve performance

Comment: Alright. Any idea about how to fix this?

Comment: Hmm, when setting the session value, try replacing `$i` with `$i++`, so you end up with `$session->set('number', $i++);`

Comment: Now I get only three elements `4` `4` `4`

Answer (score 1):

Ok I see the issue now. It's because you've overriding the session variable in the loop, each time.

Instead, try this:

> **First module**

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('second-position');

for ($i=1; $i<5; $i++) 
{
    $session->set('number', $i);

    foreach($modules as $mod)
    {
        echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($mod, $attribs);
    }
}
```

> **Second module**

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();

for ($i=1; $i<5; $i++) 
{
    echo $session->get('number' . $i);
}
```

#### Update

Don't put the loop within the loop. You can simply acheive what you want using:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();

for ($i=1; $i<5; $i++) 
{
    $session->set('number' . $i, $i);
    echo $session->get('number' . $i);
}
```

Comment: wooo! Output with this is : `4444` `4444` `4444` `4444`

Comment: @Saibbyweb - rejected your edit cause it was incorrect. I've updated my answer. Try again now

Comment: alright.. now output is : `13` `13`

Comment: removing `$i++` from both modules gives `1234` `1234` `1234` `1234` but its four times my desired output.

Comment: Ok let me do some testing and get back to you. I've never been brilliant with `for` loops

Comment: Your #1 on JSE, you're brilliant with everything.

Comment: Hmm, even by rolling back to my original post, the outcome is what you need: http://imgur.com/a/5cbJV

Comment: You have written all this code in a single PHP file. My case is different, I am using Joomla modules. :/

Comment: I also tried using different modules.

Comment: I am calling the `second for loop` inside the `first for loop`, what you have done is let them run separately which isn't my case.

Comment: Ahh I see now. Your question says they are in 2 different modules. See my updated answer

Comment: Dude they are in two different modules, I `echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($mod, $attribs);` inside the `for loop` in the first module. The module I am echoing inside the `first for loop`, has a `for loop` of its own. That's what I meant.